# addEventListener on click

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a button defined as following

In `index.html`:

```
<body>
  <section>
    <button id="open-file">Open File</button>
    ...(series of other similar buttons)...

  </section>
</body>

<script>
    require('./renderer');
</script>
```

In `renderer.js`:

```
const openFileButton = document.querySelector('#open-file');
...

openFileButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('You clicked the "Open File" button.');
});
```

In `main.js`:

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });
  mainWindow.loadFile('app/index.html');
  ...
});
```

When I click on that button in the app window, nothing happens in the console. Are there any extra steps I need to add to execute this event listener?

Comment: make sure `const openFileButton = document.querySelector('#open-file');` is executed AFTER `<button id="open-file">Open File</button>` is in the DOM - and check for errors in the browser console

Comment: Are you sure the `document.querySelector('#open-file')` returns the element? It could be a loading order issue: the renderer.js being loaded before the index.html. You could check it by adding a `console.log(openFileButton)` before the `openFileButton.addEventListener('click..` line.

Comment: @JaromandaX@Jacob van Lingen Yes, I have this ```<script>
    require('./renderer');
  </script>``` several lines after the html button declaration.

Comment: is `<button id="open-file">Open File</button>` inside a `<form>` perhaps?

Comment: @JaromandaX No, it is just a button in <section>. Updated my html code.

Comment: Open dev tools and see what happens or not, i mean/think the render process do not print on stdout

Comment: I think I know what goes wrong. The button tag is by default type=submit. Could you add `type="button"` to your code?

Comment: Ok, so I open the Dev Tools to check. The text ```You clicked the Open File button``` is actually displayed in the console there. Why isn't it displayed on the Ubuntu terminal where I run ```npm start```? Note that I tried changing the ```<script> ```part as per @expressjs123 and @osynkad as well, same result. I am editing in Atom, by the way.

Comment: @Marc So does it mean I need to send the message from ```renderer.js``` to ```main.js``` if I want to display on the linux console?

Comment: Ah, so it did work all along :D. To answer you question, it is because "The Console method log() outputs a message to the web console." - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log). The electron app runs in it's own container, so JavaScript cannot log to the linux console.

Comment: To all, thanks. I think I know the issue (as mentioned). I now use ```alert``` instead of ```console.log``` to check/debug my code. ```alert``` shows a popup window in the app itself. Closing this.

Comment: @TristanTran I think so. You can open the dev tools in the render process with: `win.webContents.openDevTools()` on the main process.

Comment: @Marc Yup, I did that to see the console.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `<script src="./renderer.js"></script>`? Are you sure your `renderer.js` runs as intended?

Just to clarify, `require()` doesn't exist in client-side JavaScript. Open your browsers developer console and you should see that `require()` isn't defined.

Take a look at [MDN script tag documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) for more information how you can include your .js files.

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML file, you're using `require` in your script tag which is a Node.js specific function. Based on what you're expecting, it looks like you would like to link renderer.js to your HTML file. Therefore, link it directly by entering `<script src="renderer.js"></script>`.